# Are nursing rooms free at Changi?

Tags: airports, singapore

The airport's [website](http://www.changiairport.com/en/airport-experience/attractions-and-services/baby-care-room.html) shows there are baby care rooms at Changi. But I cannot find anywhere if there is a fee to use the room. Are the baby care rooms free to use?

Their website also says there are strollers that can be loaned on a first-come first-serve basis (assuming they are fee free). Does anyone know if the airport has enough strollers? Are they easily available?

This is for a traveller on an international flight, transiting through Changi.

Comment: I've never heard of any airport anywhere charging for nursing/baby care rooms.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://sg.theasianparent.com/privacy-at-singapore-baby-care-room/) complains about a man barging into a baby care room at Changi airport to fill up his hot water flask, which strongly implies there is no charge to use the rooms.